# iOS UIWebview ignoring CSS line-height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, css, ios, uiwebview

I have created some web content using a HTML editor and am loading it into a `UIWebView`. Everything seems to be working fine apart from one small bit. The CSS is being loaded, but the `UIWebView` ignores the line-height CSS attribute. Font sizes are being picked up correctly

My body CSS is as follows:

```
body {
    color: #333;
    text-align: centre;
    padding: 0;
    font: 0.75em/0.8em "Lucida Grande", Lucida, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 0;
}
```

I have also tried adding a specific `line-height: 80%;` line, but it makes no difference. `UIWebView` renders the text in exactly the same way if I set the lien-height to 0.8em or 1.5em!

The HTML displays correctly when I load it in Safari on my Mac, so I presume the HTNML is ok, and other the text is not inheriting from other CSS statements. I'm lost as to what could be wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks Craig

Comment: Try adding it on a p or div element instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this on a real device and it renders correctly. This is a simulator issue :(

I was using Xcode 4.3.2 and the simulator running iOS5.1.

I will raise this as a bug with Apple, but hopefully this answer will help somebody else in the future!

Comment: Not exactly a simulator issue, is not working on 7.